# How to get fast I/O in C language?

Tags: c

How to get fast input/output in c? i have been using scanf and printf but in programming contest i am getting "Time limit exceeded" .please suggest which functions to use for fast I/O in c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
int i,j,flag,num,t,a[500000],k;
unsigned int n;
scanf("%d",&t);
if(t<=10)
{
    while(t!=0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n<=70000)
        {
            i=1;flag=1;num=3;a[0]=2;k=0;
            while(i<n)
            {
                for(j=3;(j<=sqrt(num))&&(flag==1);j++)
                {
                   if(num%j==0)
                   {
                    flag=0;
                   }

            }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                a[i]=num;
                num=num+2;
                flag=1;
                printf("%d",a[k]);
                k++;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                flag=1;
                num=num+2;
            }
           }
       }
       printf("%d",a[k]);
       t--;
       printf("\n");

    }
   }
}
```

this is the code for which i am getting "time limit exceeded"

Comment: Can you show us code where it says time limit exceeded?

Comment: It depends very much on the operating system. But in general, if you want fast I/O you should not use buffered I/O (like `scanf`/`printf` is).

Comment: and do the formating directly without having to parse a format string should help also

Comment: First, you review the algorithm. Next, you reduce the number of input and output .

Comment: Please post the exercise's description too.

Comment: `for(j=3;(j<=sqrt(num))` is terribly inefficient. You should move the sqrt call out of the loop.

Comment: @Lundin that's a problem, but any semi-decent C compiler would optimize that away. I suspect that the real problem is that he tries to solve a clever number theoretic problem via brute force...

Comment: @TamásZahola If everyone writes mediocre code and then leave all performance issues to the compiler's optimizer, then what's the point of having a programming contest?

Comment: I am a beginner in the programming contest environment.i heard of fast i/o methods which many programmers use.

Answer (score 3):

How do you know, that your program is I/O-bound? Programming contests like http://codility.com usually specify a desired time-complexity like O(N). If you submit an algorithm with O(N^2) complexity, you just cannot win, even if you use the fastest I/O library of the world.

Comment: programming contest of spoj .com

Comment: @user39555 I guess it's the second problem, right? ( http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/ )

Comment: No,its from programming club contest of our college

Answer (score 0):

printf/scanf is buffered I/O. It first catch I/O in buffer. You can use [fflush()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) function to flush buffer in memory.

Comment: what does fflush() function do? i have no idea about this

Comment: @user39555 Use fflush() after printf/scanf

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` and `puts` should be substantially faster than formatted IO.